# if else statement with button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button

i am working on quiz game project
i finished almost everything
but i have to calc the scores for every question but i don't know how to use conditional statement with buttons
like
if button_selected is A then mark obtained is 1
finally the program calc all the marks and print "your total marks is 85%"

below is a part of my code (questions):

```
q1 = Label(win1, text="What is the main memory in computer?: ", font="Times 20", bg="white")
q1.pack()
q1.place(x=0, y=40)

button1 = Button(win1, text="A. Dynamic RAM ", font="Times 17", fg="blue",variable=radio,value=1 ,command=selection)# true
button1.place(x=0, y=80)

button2 = Button(win1, text=" B. Static RAM ", font="Times 17", variable=radio,value=0 ,fg="blue", command=selection)
button2.place(x=0, y=120)

button3 = Button(win1, text=" C. ROM ", font="Times 17", fg="blue",variable=radio,value=1 , command=selection)
button3.place(x=0, y=160)

button4 = Button(win1, text=" D. Register", font="Times 17", fg="blue",variable=radio,value=1 ,command=selection)
button4.place(x=0, y=200)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no attributes like `variable` and `value` for a `Button` in Tkinter. Just pass the option chosen as an argument with the function `selection` with each button's command (for that you can use `lambda`.)

In the function `selection`, check for correct answers and update the score.

```
from tkinter import *

win1 = Tk()
win1.geometry("600x500")

score=0
def selection(optionChose):
    global score
    if optionChose == 'A':
        score+=1
    else:
        score+=0 #can also do negative marking for wrong 
    print(score)
    
q1 = Label(win1, text="What is the main memory in computer?: ", font="Times 20", bg="white")
q1.pack()
q1.place(x=0, y=40)

button1 = Button(win1, text="A. Dynamic RAM ", font="Times 17", fg="blue" ,command=lambda:selection('A'))# true
button1.place(x=0, y=80)

button2 = Button(win1, text=" B. Static RAM ", font="Times 17",fg="blue", command=lambda:selection('B'))
button2.place(x=0, y=120)

button3 = Button(win1, text=" C. ROM ", font="Times 17", fg="blue", command=lambda:selection('C'))
button3.place(x=0, y=160)

button4 = Button(win1, text=" D. Register", font="Times 17", fg="blue",command=lambda:selection('D'))
button4.place(x=0, y=200)

win1.mainloop()
```

---

For building a better version using `Radiobuttons` as options instead of `Buttons`, refer to [MCQ Quiz Game using Tkinter](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-mcq-quiz-game-using-tkinter/) (`JSON data` will be used to extract the question & answers from.)

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this is to pass an argument from the button to the callback function. One way to do this is using a lambda function:

```
from tkinter import *

win1 = Tk()

q1 = Label(win1, text="What is the main memory in computer?: ")
q1.pack()

def selection(button):
    print(button)

button1 = Button(win1, text="A. Dynamic RAM ", command=lambda:selection('A'))
button1.pack()  #               Parameter passed to callback function ---^

button2 = Button(win1, text=" B. Static RAM ", command=lambda:selection('B'))
button2.pack()  #               Parameter passed to callback function ---^

win1.mainloop()
```